# make Simple Video Chatting and live streaming with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, php, html

i made Video Chatting with WebRTC by using this tutorials https://www.kirupa.com/html5/simple_video_chat_with_webrtc.htm
but the app not support more than 2 person in the room i tried change 
const isOfferer = members.length === 2; to const isOfferer = members.length === 3; but not worked 
i need help in make the room accept more than two and need to be able make live streaming video all people in the page can see it without chatting with me 
 the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.scaledrone.com/scaledrone.min.js'></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #0098ff;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 0 50px;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
    }
    video {
      background: white;
      background-image: url(https://www.kirupa.com/images/orange_logo_svg.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: contain;
      max-width: calc(50% - 5%);
      margin: 0 5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .copy {
      position: fixed;
      top: 25px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      font-size: 18px;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="copy">Send your URL to a friend to start a video call</div>
  <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
  <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the javascript file

i tried to edit

```
// Generate random room name if needed
if (!location.hash) {
  location.hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}
const roomHash = location.hash.substring(1);

// TODO: Replace with your own channel ID
const drone = new ScaleDrone('2xmbUiTsqTzukyf7');
// Room name needs to be prefixed with 'observable-'
const roomName = 'observable-' + roomHash;
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};
let room;
let pc;


function onSuccess() {};
function onError(error) {
  console.error(error);
};

drone.on('open', error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  room = drone.subscribe(roomName);
  room.on('open', error => {
    if (error) {
      onError(error);
    }
  });
  // We're connected to the room and received an array of 'members'
  // connected to the room (including us). Signaling server is ready.
  room.on('members', members => {
    console.log('MEMBERS', members);
    // If we are the second user to connect to the room we will be creating the offer
    const isOfferer = members.length === 2;
    startWebRTC(isOfferer);
  });
});

// Send signaling data via Scaledrone
function sendMessage(message) {
  drone.publish({
    room: roomName,
    message
  });
}

function startWebRTC(isOfferer) {
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

  // 'onicecandidate' notifies us whenever an ICE agent needs to deliver a
  // message to the other peer through the signaling server
  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({'candidate': event.candidate});
    }
  };

  // If user is offerer let the 'negotiationneeded' event create the offer
  if (isOfferer) {
    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      pc.createOffer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
    }
  }

  // When a remote stream arrives display it in the #remoteVideo element
  pc.onaddstream = event => {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  }).then(stream => {
    // Display your local video in #localVideo element
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // Add your stream to be sent to the conneting peer
    pc.addStream(stream);
  }, onError);

  // Listen to signaling data from Scaledrone
  room.on('data', (message, client) => {
    // Message was sent by us
    if (client.id === drone.clientId) {
      return;
    }

    if (message.sdp) {
      // This is called after receiving an offer or answer from another peer
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), () => {
        // When receiving an offer lets answer it
        if (pc.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {
          pc.createAnswer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
        }
      }, onError);
    } else if (message.candidate) {
      // Add the new ICE candidate to our connections remote description
      pc.addIceCandidate(
        new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate), onSuccess, onError
      );
    }
  });
}

function localDescCreated(desc) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(
    desc,
    () => sendMessage({'sdp': pc.localDescription}),
    onError
  );
}
```

Comment: You need a server to relay the calls.  Otherwise, the more people you add, the more connections you'll need... exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup separate connections for each user in the room. See: [WebRTC with 3 users connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885362/webrtc-with-3-users-connection)

Comment: This is probably more clear for you: https://blog.mgechev.com/2014/12/26/multi-user-video-conference-webrtc-angularjs-yeoman/