# webRTC streaming latency and bandwidth issues in many-to-many call

Tags: webrtc, communication, kurento

I am working on webRtc and i am facing so many problems like
streaming latency and video hang issues.

When 2 people connected to the same room(many-to-many) the videos stream fine and users receive and send the video in normal manner but when more users connect to the room the streaming become slow and even it hangs.

How to fix this issue? or webrtc is not capable to handle more users? because there are so many bandwidth and cpu usage issues and in the testing ,maximum 3 connections work fine after that it hangs.

Comment: Did you check load in CPU and bandwidth after adding the third user? Do you use different machines for each client?

Comment: Are you using a [mesh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31495407/918910)? You may need an MCU or a Router solution.

Comment: are you talking about Bandwidth for user network or bandwidth for server?  - igracia?

Comment: I am using kurento many to many tutorial.I need to know about MCU or Router solution .Would you please define these terms because I am newbie @jib

Comment: Follow my mesh link above. I have links to those terms there.

Comment: I know about mesh but I am working on the application that should perform these tasks.

One admin should broadcast his audio+video to all the users and should receive audio+video of one user at a time when selected.

Kindly help me .is there any tutorial or demo close to this functionality.?
-@jib